# Where to find non-standard drawer pulls?

Tags: hardware, drawers

I'm in progress on a kitchen refresh and my drawer pulls are non-standard size (4-7/8" center-to-center). I never thought it would be this difficult to find brass drawer pulls that fit this size. Does anyone know of a good outlet to find drawer pulls with this sizing? Google and Amazon are no help at all.

Comment: They exist: https://www.thehardwarehut.com/catalog-product.php?p_ref=275840 but maybe you need an oversized backplate to cover the holes.

Comment: Plug the holes, drill new holes to suit new pulls, done.

Comment: I’d try Restoration Hardware.